# Android Studio: Importing Eclipse project from SVN along with Library projects

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am able to import the main project along with two other library projects from SVN. But while in the process if I select,

1. "Create project from existing sources" it creates the project and after doing some modifications in Project settings it works. But I could not find the Gradle file and it gives error "The project 'CrossConnectRefactored' is not a Gradle-based project" if I select the Gradle icon.

[image]

2. If I select "Import project from external model -> Gradle", it creates the project but still without 'Gradle' file and it gives the similar error.
3. If I first Export the project from Eclipse using 'Android -> Generate Gradle build files' and import the same in AndroidStudio then it creates all the required Gradle files properly. But I didn't get option to build/run the project and it always says 'Gradle project sync failed. Basic function...'.
   It also gives the below error,

[image]

Could anyone please help me out with the 1st or 2nd option?